# Property without setter cannot be assigned to

Tags: c#, specflow

I am writing a spec flow test with three columns...
example:

```
|Field  | Key       | Value |
|A      | aa        |   ""  |
|       | bb        |   ""  |
|       | cc        |   33  |
|       | dd        |   1   |
|B      | aa        |   5   |
|       | bb        |   4   |
|       | cc        |   2   |
|       | dd        |   ""  |
```

I added this method to read data from the table:

```
      var elements = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>().ToList();
        var data = table.CreateSet<SpecFlowData>();
        elements.AddRange(collection: from item in data
                              let field =item.Field
                              let key = item.Key
                              let value = item.Value
                               select new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>()
                                  {
                                      Keys = field,
                                      Values = new Dictionary<string,string>()
                                          {
                                              Keys= key,
                                              Values = value

                                          } 

                                  }

                              );
```

I am trying to assign a key value pair for each field in the first column.But I get error "Property without setter cannot be assigned to" while building the code. Any idea is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign `Keys` and `Values` to `Dictionary<>` directly. But you can project `data` to proper `Dictionary` of `Dictionaries` using LINQ:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(i => i.Field, (k, v) => new
                          {
                             Key = k,
                             Values = v.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)
                          })
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Values);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't specifically set the `Dictionary<,>.Keys` or `Dictionary<,>.Values` properties. They are only `get` properties. You need to loop through your values and use the `Add(Key, Value)` or use the [LINQ `ToDictionary<TSource, TKey>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.